# How can I change the color of a SpriteRenderer using a hexadecimal string representation?

Tags: unity

I tried to give color like below but unity doesn't accept the format
`spriteRenderer.color = "#ffffff"`.

How can I give a hex color to a `SpriteRenderer` in Unity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString`

```
   //define a color variable
   Color newCol;
   //if we successfully parse html color string
    if (ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString(htmlValue, out newCol))
    //then set the colour
        property.colorValue = newCol;
```

[ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString.html)